# CiBonfire: URL Redirect after clicking "Next"

Tags: php, codeigniter, bonfire

After I click "Next" at initial set up in CiBonfire I am redirected to 'me.ie/public/' however the project is located at 'me.ie/starter/public/'

I can manually type in '/starter/' each time but it is a little frustrating and from what I can recall in the past, I never had to do this. Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance, Niall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you install CiBonfire under a subdirectory called "starter".  This is what I did (XAMPP + bonfire v0.7):

[1] Browse to *starter/index.php*, prepend "/starter" to URL in line #2 as shown below

```
$install_url = 'http'.((empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) or $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'off')?'':'s') .'://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] .'/starter/public/';
```

You can then proceed with the installation.

[2] Change **1.htaccess** in *ci-bonfire/public/* to **.htaccess**, then update line #158, change to your subdirectory name

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /starter
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^bonfire/codeigniter.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have Windows 8.1 Pro 64bit Laptop. I want to install `Ci-bonfire` can you please advise me what is the best way. I tried lot of articles. But wont work. Can you explain it from the beginning.